# Generate array of key value by searching one array in another array

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to building an application in which 2 arrays is there, second array is getting applying **rsort** to first array.

```
$array_1 = array('20','30','30','20');
$array_2 = array('30','30','20','20');
```

i want generate a new array by searching array_1 in array_2 and return key values, ie

```
$key_array = array('2','0','1','3');
```

I tried like

```
$array_1 = array('20','30','30','20');
$array_2 = $array_1;

rsort($array_2);
$first_keys = array();
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$arr1){
    $first_keys[] = array_search($arr1, $array_2);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($first_keys);
```

but its getting **2,0,0,2**

I also tried replacing current key by 'xx'.but it also printing 2,0,0,2

```
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$arr1){
    $array_1[$key] = 'xx';
    $first_keys[] = array_search($arr1, $array_2);
}
```

Comment: on what basis to get this output? I am kind of confuse

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove from $array2 the value on each search, while preserving the array references. This should work (can't test here):

```
$array_1 = array('20','30','30','20');
$array_2 = $array_1;

rsort($array_2);
$first_keys = array();
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$arr1){
     $key= array_search($arr1, $array_2);
     $first_keys[] = $key;
     $array_2[$key]="";
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($first_keys);
```

Comment: Thnks...figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove searched key from second array.

Unset that key from second array.(working)

```
$array_1 = array('20','30','30','20');

$array_2 = $array_1;

rsort($array_2);

$first_keys = array();
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$arr1){
    $searchKey = array_search($arr1, $array_2);
    $first_keys[] = $searchKey;
    unset($array_2[$searchKey]);

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($first_keys);
```